# Hystrix Command property ignoreExceptions is not working expectedly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, netflix

Using Hystrix command to invoke a default functionality and also have an API exception handler which is handling the exceptions and letting user/client know about the error that happened but while my server is UP, @HystrixCommand function is still getting called while my custom exception handler is being ignored instead of using **ignoreExceptions** property of @HystrixCommand annotation.

Please guide me how to make this work.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.exception.FactorNotCreatedException;
import com.example.demo.exception.NotFoundException;
import com.example.demo.feignClient.ConversionFactorProxyClient;
import com.example.demo.model.ConversionFactor;
import com.example.demo.model.CurrencyConversion;
import com.example.demo.model.FactorResponse;
import com.example.demo.service.ConvertService;
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixException;

import feign.FeignException;

@RestController
public class ConvertCurrencyController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private ConversionFactorProxyClient cnvFacCl;
    @Autowired
    private ConvertService convertServ;

    @GetMapping(value = "/currency-converter/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackConvertCurrency")
    public ResponseEntity<?> convertCurrency(@PathVariable String from, @PathVariable String to,
            @PathVariable double quantity) {
        logger.info("Inside convertCurrency() :: get Conversion factor ");
        FactorResponse fr = cnvFacCl.getConversionFactor(from, to).getBody();
        logger.info("{}", fr);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(convertServ.getCurrencyConverted(from, to, fr, quantity));
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/add_exchange_detail")
      @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackAddConversionFactor",
      ignoreExceptions = { FactorNotCreatedException.class,
      HttpMessageNotReadableException.class, MissingPathVariableException.class,
      TypeMismatchException.class, MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
      ConstraintViolationException.class,
      HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class, NotFoundException.class,
      FeignException.class},
      raiseHystrixExceptions =
      {HystrixException.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION} )

    public ResponseEntity<?> addConversionFactor(@RequestBody ConversionFactor cf) {
        ;
        logger.info("Inside addConversionFactor() :: add conversion factory for a country ");
        List<ConversionFactor> list = cnvFacCl.addConversionFactor(cf).getBody();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
    }


     // ******************************FALLBACK  Methods*****************************************

      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      private ResponseEntity<?> fallbackConvertCurrency(@PathVariable String from, @PathVariable String to, @PathVariable double quantity) {
          return ResponseEntity.ok(new CurrencyConversion(from, to, 0.00, quantity, 0.00)); 
          }


      @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
      private ResponseEntity<?> fallbackAddConversionFactor(@RequestBody ConversionFactor cf){
          return ResponseEntity.ok(new ConversionFactor(0000l, "US", "IN", 75.64)); 
          }



}    /*
inside exception handler class */

package com.example.demo.exception;

import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import com.example.demo.feignClient.model.ApiException;

import feign.FeignException;
//import feign.Response;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    //incase content is not created due to some internal error
        @ExceptionHandler(value = {FactorNotCreatedException.class})
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleFactorNotCreatedException(FactorNotCreatedException ex){

            HttpStatus error = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            int status = error.value();

            ApiException apiException = new ApiException
                    (
                        ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")),
                       status, 
                       error,
                       ex.getMessage()
                       );

            return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, error);
        }

    //incase content not found 
        @ExceptionHandler(value = {NotFoundException.class})
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFoundException(NotFoundException ex){

            HttpStatus error = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
            int status = error.value();

            ApiException apiException = new ApiException
                    (
                        ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")),
                       status, 
                       error,
                       ex.getMessage()
                       );

            return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, error);
        }

    @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleFeignStatusException(FeignException e, HttpServletResponse response) {

//      response.setStatus(e.status());

        int status = e.status();
        HttpStatus error = HttpStatus.resolve(status);

        ApiException apiException = new ApiException
                (
                    ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")),
                   status, 
                   error,
                   e.getMessage()
                   );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, error);
    }


    //incase of updation, constraint voilation (i.e. @PathVariable and @Requestbody)
        @ExceptionHandler({
                HttpMessageNotReadableException.class,
                MissingPathVariableException.class,
                TypeMismatchException.class,
                MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
                ConstraintViolationException.class,
                HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class
                })
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequestException(Exception ex){
            HttpStatus error = null;
            if(ex instanceof HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) {
                 error = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
            }
            else {
            error = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
            }
            int status = error.value();
            ApiException apiException = new ApiException
                    (
                        ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")),
                       status, 
                       error,
                       ex.getMessage()
                       );

            return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, error);
        }

}
```